# XSLT to regroup XML data dynamically from FMPXMLRESULT using only XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, filemaker, xslt-grouping

I need to transform XML data from one structure to another. I need the target XML to be structured based on metadata inside the source XML. The source XML has a fixed structure, however the structure of the target XML needs to be built dynamically (including tag names and data groupings) based on metadata in the source XML.

The following source XML provides an example of the structure. The source XML will always use the FMPXMLRESULT structure.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ID" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Description" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Customer" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderItem::ProductName" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderItem::UnitPrice" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderItem::Quantity" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderItem::TaxCode" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderItem::Total" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderTaxCode::TaxCode" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderTaxCode::TaxRate" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
  </METADATA>
  <RESULTSET FOUND="2">
    <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1">
      <COL><DATA>1</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>Order for first project</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>Customer No 1</DATA></COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>Product A</DATA>
        <DATA>Product B</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>10.50</DATA>
        <DATA>12.10</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>2</DATA>
        <DATA>1</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>VAT</DATA>
        <DATA>VAT0</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>21</DATA>
        <DATA>12.1</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>VAT</DATA>
        <DATA>VAT0</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>0.2</DATA>
        <DATA>0</DATA>
      </COL>
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="2">
      <COL><DATA>2</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>Order for second project</DATA></COL>
      <COL><DATA>Customer No 2</DATA></COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>Product 2A</DATA>
        <DATA>Product 2B</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>1.50</DATA>
        <DATA>345</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>17</DATA>
        <DATA>2</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>VAT0</DATA>
        <DATA>VAT</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>25.5</DATA>
        <DATA>690</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>VAT</DATA>
        <DATA>VAT0</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>0.2</DATA>
        <DATA>0</DATA>
      </COL>
    </ROW>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

Given the above XML (including metadata) the target XML format would be as follows.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderBatch>
  
  <Order>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Description>Order for first project</Description>
    <Customer>Customer No 1</Customer>
    <OrderItem>
      <ProductName>Product A</ProductName>
      <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <TaxCode>VAT</TaxCode>
      <Total>21</Total>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <ProductName>Product B</ProductName>
      <UnitPrice>12.10</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <TaxCode>VAT0</TaxCode>
      <Total>12.1</Total>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderTaxCode>
      <TaxCode>VAT</TaxCode>
      <TaxRate>0.2</TaxRate>
    </OrderTaxCode>
    <OrderTaxCode>
      <TaxCode>VAT0</TaxCode>
      <TaxRate>0</TaxRate>
    </OrderTaxCode>
  </Order>

  <Order>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Description>Order for second project</Description>
    <Customer>Customer No 2</Customer>
    <OrderItem>
      <ProductName>Product 2A</ProductName>
      <UnitPrice>1.50</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>17</Quantity>
      <TaxCode>VAT0</TaxCode>
      <Total>25.5</Total>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <ProductName>Product 2B</ProductName>
      <UnitPrice>345</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <TaxCode>VAT</TaxCode>
      <Total>690</Total>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderTaxCode>
      <TaxCode>VAT</TaxCode>
      <TaxRate>0.2</TaxRate>
    </OrderTaxCode>
    <OrderTaxCode>
      <TaxCode>VAT0</TaxCode>
      <TaxRate>0</TaxRate>
    </OrderTaxCode>
  </Order>

</OrderBatch>
```

Different metadata in the source XML would produce a different target XML. The general rules are as follows

1. The field names are contained in METADATA and the data is contained in RESULTSET
2. The COL nodes in each ROW of RESULTSET correspond to the FIELD nodes in METADATA by position
3. Any RESULTSET/FIELD where the NAME contains the text "::" should be considered as 'grouped' data
4. Grouped data should have a group name equal to the text preceding "::" (this symbol will only ever appear once in a FIELD NAME)
5. Grouped data COL nodes may contain 0, 1 or more DATA child nodes
6. FIELD nodes that are not grouped (i.e. NAME doesn't contain "::") will always have exactly 1 DATA child node in the COL node
7. Grouped data fields will always be adjacent (e.g. all fields in the group ORDERITEM:: won't have fields from other groups in between them in the field order)
8. The group names, field names and field order are not known in advance and may change, **the XSLT needs to handle this dynamically**. The above XML is a good example of the sort of thing that will need to be handled
9. I can only use XSLT 1.0
10. FMPDSORESULT is a deprecated technology and I can't use it

The 2 major sticking points are

1. Pulling DATA nodes out of COL nodes by position and assigning to their own groups
2. Achieving what is needed with the metadata separate

I've tried a number of approaches with nested for-each loops, and different ways of organising templates. I wonder if perhaps creating an internal data structure might be the way to go, but I also may be looking at the problem wrong?

Here is the best I've come up with so far, it's the closest I've come but still not nearly close enough

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


  <!-- the key indexes the METADATA fields by their position -->
  <xsl:key
    name="fieldList"
    match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD"
    use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1"
  />

  <!-- template for the data section of the FileMaker XML -->
  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <OrderBatch>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" />
    </OrderBatch>
  </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for each row -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
        <!-- for each row, create Order element and apply the relevant template for each column -->
    <Order>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL" />
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for each column within each row -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
        <!-- set $qualified with the name of the field - this will be qualified with the table occurrence if related -->
    <xsl:variable name="qualified" select="string(key('fieldList', position())/@NAME)"/>
    <!-- set $group with the name of the field's group -->
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="substring-before($qualified, '::')"/>
        <!-- set $name to a value for use as an XML element -->
        <xsl:variable name="name">
            <xsl:choose>

                <!-- if the qualified field is related (contains "::") then remove the table occurrence name -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($qualified, '::')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($qualified, '::')"/>
            </xsl:when>

                <!-- if the qualified field is not related then just return the field name -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$qualified"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>



    <!-- create the element with the field's name and use the data as the element's value -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- related element - need to group -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($qualified, '::')">
        <!-- group each DATA element in turn -->
        <!-- actually only need to run this on the first COL in a group - but I'll figure that out later -->
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:DATA">
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$group" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="$name" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- element is at top level so just create the field/value -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for grouping DATA nodes across multiple COL nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:DATA">
    <xsl:param name = "pGroup" />
    <xsl:param name = "pName" />
    <xsl:element name="{$pGroup}">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../fmp:COL" mode="group">
          <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="$pGroup" />
          <xsl:with-param name="pName" select="$pName" />
          <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for cycling through COL nodes and getting the DATA node if it belongs to the specified group -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:COL" mode="group">
    <xsl:param name = "pGroup" />
    <xsl:param name = "pName" />
    <xsl:param name = "pos" /> <!-- this will help select the correct DATA node - not sure how to use it yet though -->
    <xsl:variable name="qualified" select="string(key('fieldList', position())/@NAME)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="colGroup" select="substring-before($qualified, '::')"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($qualified, '::') and $pGroup = $colGroup">
      <xsl:element name="substring-after($qualified, '::')">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I understand that this isn't easy and isn't a normal way of using XSLT (it would normally be written to fit the target structure), however I believe this is a solvable problem and XSLT seems to be capable of far more complex tasks.

Any help on how to solve this would be very welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.  You will need to work out the prefix to use the node-set function as noted.  You can verify assumptions and make adjustments.  Let me know, if you have questions.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="metadata">
    <xsl:for-each select="//fmp:FIELD">
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@NAME"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($name, '::')">
            <xsl:element name="parent">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '::')"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="child">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($name, '::')"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="parent">
              <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="child"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>  
        <xsl:element name="position">
          <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- NOTE:  Replace msxml with your prefix that converts RTF's to node sets.  -->
  <xsl:variable name="metadataList" select="msxml:node-set($metadata)"/>

  <!-- Get a distinct list of parent elements.  -->
  <xsl:variable name="parents">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$metadataList/element[not(parent = preceding-sibling::element/parent)]"/>  
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="parentList" select="msxml:node-set($parents)"/>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <xsl:element name="OrderBatch">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
    <xsl:variable name="rowNode" select="."/> 
    <xsl:element name="Order">
      <!-- Loop thru the distinct list of parents.  -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$parentList/element">
        <xsl:variable name="parent" select="parent"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstSetPosition" select="position"/>
        <!-- Loop thru on the first set of data nodes for this parent.  -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$rowNode/fmp:COL[number($firstSetPosition)]/fmp:DATA">
          <xsl:variable name="dataposition" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:element name="{$parent}">
            <!-- Loop thru all the child nodes for this parent.  -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$metadataList/element[parent = $parent]">
              <xsl:variable name="position" select="position"/>
              <xsl:variable name="child" select="string(child)"/>
              <xsl:choose>
                <!-- When the parent has no child nodes.  -->
                <xsl:when test="$child = ''">
                  <xsl:value-of select="string($rowNode/fmp:COL[number($position)]/fmp:DATA[$dataposition])"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:element name="{$child}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string($rowNode/fmp:COL[number($position)]/fmp:DATA[$dataposition])"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>  
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:DATA">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and better than the one I arrived at. It doesn't require a 'pk' field to be included in the export order and doesn't require the children of groups to be adjacent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the FMPXMLRESULT grammar is that it allows you to change your solution's field names without breaking your XSLT stylesheet. The output element and attribute names are supposed to conform to your target application's XML schema and be hard-coded into the stylesheet.

Therefore I would suggest you ignore the field names contained in the METADATA section, and base your transformation solely on the position of the fields in the field export order. Otherwise you should be using the FMPDSORESULT grammar, where you can change the field export order, but not the field names.

With this in mind, your stylesheet could look like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <OrderBatch>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
            <Order>
                <!-- order -->
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </ID>
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </Description>
                <Customer>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[3]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </Customer>
                <!-- items -->
                <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <OrderItem>
                        <ProductName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </ProductName>
                        <UnitPrice>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
                        </UnitPrice>
                        <Quantity>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
                        </Quantity>
                        <TaxCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[7]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
                        </TaxCode>
                        <Total>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
                        </Total>
                    </OrderItem>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- tax codes -->
                <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <OrderTaxCode>
                        <TaxCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </TaxCode>
                        <TaxRate>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
                        </TaxRate>
                    </OrderTaxCode>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </OrderBatch>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I could certainly write the XSLT with the target names hard-coded however the field export order could change (though the field names will always stay the same) so I was hoping for a way to use the METADATA to handle this. As far as I understand it XSLT could achieve what I want to do (it seems to be capable of way more complex tasks) and I'd really like XSLT that can do it.

Comment: Also, I ruled out using FMPDSORESULT due to it being a deprecated technology and this solution needs to be future proofed. Edited the OP with an update.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand the purpose of this exercise. Normally, the export is intended to be consumed by a target application and the purpose of the transformation is to create a document in the target's application's schema.Therefore your field names are irrelevant. OTOH, the field export order must be set in stone.

Comment: In the unlikely case that you do need the original field names, I suggest - again - you use the FMPDSORESULT grammar. True, it has been "deprecated" since version 6 to 7 - but it is still with us. And **nothing** is "future-proofed": any feature can be changed or removed, with or without notice. Yes, it is possible to transform even FMPXMLRESULT the way you want - but I am not going to spend time on it.

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I took a 2 pass approach in the XSLT and used the xmlns:exslt extension.

As has been pointed out there really is no such thing as a totally generic solution, nor one that is fully future-proofed, however the solution I have here is close enough for my needs. I've commented/documented the code below. Hopefully others will find it useful or even improve on it in the future.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!--
  NOTES ON NON-GENERALISED ELEMENTS

  REQUIRED NODE - <pk>
  each record in the source XML must contain a node named <pk> for the following to work
  this is required when defining the matching criteria for the xsl:key "KeyGroups", and anywhere that needs to match this key
  the <pk> node is used in the second pass, the name of the <pk> node would need to be amended in all 3 places in the second pass if it needed changing

  SPECIFIC NODE NAMES - this information can't be derived from the source document
  OrderBatch - is the name of the root node that will contain the target XML
  Order - is the name of each of the record nodes inside the container
  these node names can be changed as long as every instance of them is changed throughout the document

  OVERRIDE FIELD NAMES - there is a section in the first pass that allows the renaming of field names (by substituting the fully qualified field name for a custom string)
  the code should still work without any renaming as the renaming serves no functional purpose it is merely a way to tidy field names up if needed
  -->


  <!-- index the METADATA fields by their position -->
  <xsl:key
    name="KeyMetaData"
    match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD"
    use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1"
  />



  <!-- ### FIRST PASS ### -->

  <!-- set the results of the first pass into $firstPassResult, this will then be used in the second pass -->
  <xsl:variable name="firstPassResult">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="firstPass"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- template to start reading the data from FMPXMLRESULT -->
  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT" mode="firstPass">
    <OrderBatch>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" mode="firstPass" />
    </OrderBatch>
  </xsl:template>

    <!-- template for each row in FMPXMLRESULT -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW" mode="firstPass">
        <!-- for each row, create Order element and apply the relevant template for each column -->
    <Order>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL" mode="firstPass" />
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for each column in FMPXMLRESULT -->
  <xsl:template match="fmp:COL" mode="firstPass">
        <!-- set $qualified with the name of the field - this will be qualified with the table occurrence if related -->
    <xsl:variable name="qualified" select="string(key('KeyMetaData', position())/@NAME)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="translate(substring-before($qualified, '::'), ' :.', '')"/>

        <!-- set $name to a value for use as an XML element -->
        <xsl:variable name="name">
            <xsl:choose>

                <!-- ################################################## -->
                <!-- SPECIFIC FIELD NAME OVERRIDES HERE -->
                <xsl:when test="$qualified = 'order.order_revision.company_CUSTOMER::company_name'"><xsl:value-of select="'CustomerName'"/></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$qualified = 'order.order_revision.company_SUPPLIER::company_name'"><xsl:value-of select="'SupplierName'"/></xsl:when>
                <!-- ################################################## -->

                <!-- if the qualified field is related (contains "::") then $name shouldn't include the table occurrence name -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($qualified, '::')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after($qualified, '::'), ' :.', '')"/>
            </xsl:when>

                <!-- if the qualified field is not related then qualified will be the field name -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate($qualified, ' :.', '')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- create the element with the field's name and use the data as the element's value -->
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:DATA">
            <xsl:element name="{$name}">
        <!-- include some attributes for elements that need to be grouped in the next pass -->
                <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:DATA | following-sibling::fmp:DATA) > 0">
          <!-- add an attribute 'g' to indicate the name of the group it belongs to -->
          <xsl:attribute name="g">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$group" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
          <!-- add an attribute 'n' to indicate the which iteration of the data this is -->
          <xsl:attribute name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:DATA) + 1" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
        <!-- populate with data from the original node -->
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>



  <!-- ### SECOND PASS ### -->

  <!-- the second pass uses $firstPassResult (converted to a node set using namepsace exslt:node-set as declared in header) -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($firstPassResult)" mode="secondPass"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for the outer container -->
  <xsl:template match="OrderBatch" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Order" mode="secondPass" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for each record -->
  <xsl:template match="Order" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:call-template name="grouping" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- index unique groups, uniqueness is based on
  attribute @g - the group as defined in first pass
  attribute @n - the data iteration as defined in first pass
  the parent record's <pk> node - the requirement of this node is an unfortunate but manageable constraint on the source data -->
  <xsl:key name="KeyGroups" match="*[@n]" use="concat(@g,'+',@n,'+',../pk)" />

  <!-- the grouping template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="grouping" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="secondPass"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template to match the first element with each @gr value -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@n][generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('KeyGroups', concat(@g,'+',@n,'+',../pk))[1])]" priority="2" mode="secondPass">
   <xsl:element name="{@g}">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('KeyGroups', concat(@g,'+',@n,'+',../pk))">
        <xsl:call-template name="grouping" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore subsequent nodes, they're handled within the first element template -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@n]" priority="1" mode="secondPass" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```